# Error insufficient privilege's to complete operation - power automate with MS Graph

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to use the HTTP premium connector to get Office 365 user licenses for users using graph.
I have followed similar articles [here](https://www.expiscornovus.com/2022/03/04/list-inactive-users-via-graph-api/)

But when I run my flow i keep getting error : insufficient privilege's to complete operation

I have setup App registration  and admin granted consent to the following (click below)

https://ibb.co/TvFZLHr

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph requests described in the blog post you linked require `AuditLog.Read.All` permission, which is not one of the permissions you've given the app based on the screen capture you include with your question.

You can see this in the blog post:

[image: Blog post screen capture]

An you can see it in the [Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta):

[image: Microsoft Graph API documentation]

Also note that the document states that you need an Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license.

Comment: Thanks Rob.I used another connector (Invoke HTTP Azure AD) and it worked